# What happens to Neron-Ogg-Shfarevich when characteristic of the residue field equals the prime at which Tate module is considered?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, local-fields

Neron-Ogg-Shafarevich criterion states that an elliptic curve $E$ over a local field $K$ has a good reduction if and only if the Tate module $T_{\ell}(E)$ is unramified for some prime $\ell$ which does not equal the characteristic of $k$, the residue field of $K$.

Just from curiosity I was wondering is there anything one can say when the characteritic of $k$ is equal to $\ell$? Any comments are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The correct condition in this case is that the Tate module is "crystalline" (provided $K$ has characteristic $0$). If you search this on google you really find many papers about this. See e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0605326.pdf

Comment: SGA7, Exp. IX, Thm. 5.10 (the hypothesis ${\rm{char}}(K)=0$ there can be dropped since deJong later proved the equicharacteristic-$\ell$ case of Tate's result on extending homomorphisms between generic fibers of $\ell$-divisible groups over a discrete valuation ring).

Comment: Just to clarify @DanielLoughran's comment, there are two quite distinct equivalences involved: an abelian variety over an $\ell$-adic field has good reduction if and only if its $\ell$-adic Tate module arises from an $\ell$-divisible group over the valuation ring (this is the result in SGA7 mentioned above, and there is no way around it), and an $\ell$-adic representation of the Galois group of such a field (with perfect residue field) arises from an $\ell$-divisible group over the valuation ring if and only if it is crystalline with Hodge-Tate weights in $\{0,1\}$.